# Is it good practice to store copies of the same shared pointers in different vectors?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, c++03

I have a base class, `BaseObject`, and two derived class `DerivedObject1` and `DerivedObject2`. They share a common behavior and methods, but `DerivedObject1` has an additional method. My main class `MyClass` stores (in `std::vector`) `boost::shared_ptr` of instances of those classes. `MyClass` needs to call `commonMethod()` for all the BaseObject, and sometimes call `additionalMethod()` for all DerivedObject1.

```
class BaseObject
{
  virtual void commonMethod();
}

Class DerivedObject1 : public BaseObject
{
  void commonMethod();
  void additionalMethod();
}

Class DerivedObject2 : public BaseObject
{
  void commonMethod();
}
```

Are there any disadvantages of having two vectors in `MyClass`, one that stores ALL the pointers of `DerivedObject1` and `DerivedObject2`, and another vector that stores only the pointers of `DerivedObject1` ? Meaning I would have all the `DerivedObject1` pointers twice. But I think the call to the different methods would be clear, at least.

```
class MyClass
{
  typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseObject>> BaseObjectVector;
  typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DerivedObject1>> DerivedObject1Vector;
  BaseObjectVector everything;
  DerivedObject1Vector only_derived1;

  void doSomething()
  {
    for (BaseObjectVector::iterator iter = everything.begin(); iter != everything.end(); ++iter)
    {
      (*iter)->commonMethod();
    }
  }

  void doSomethingForDerivedObject1()
  {
    for (DerivedObject1Vector::iterator iter = only_derived1.begin(); iter != only_derived1.end(); ++iter)
    {
      (*iter)->additionalMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

I can think of other ways to do this, mainly having one vector for `DerivedObject1` and one vector for `DerivedObject2`, but to call `commonMethod()`, I would have to iterate over both vectors. My original solution seems the best to me, except that some pointers are stored twice. What are the disadvantages of this ?

Comment: Why can't DerivedObject1 inherit from DerivedObject2? Then doesn't the problem go away?

Comment: Any reason why you can't uplift `additionalMethod()` into the base class and just make it a do nothing function for `DerivedObject2`?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please *show* it to us. Preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Yes sorry, it's boost::shared_ptr, will edit, I'm switching between versions and getting confused

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with having multiple `shared_ptr`s to the same object. It's kind of the *point* of `shared_ptr` (although in C++03 you don't have `unique_ptr` and `reference_wrapper`, which might be preferable here)

Comment: Thank you Bathsheba and NathanOliver, I answered those propositions in a comment to sagi's answer

Comment: Edited the question to add the code, thank you @Someprogrammerdude for the reminder

Comment: [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might be an alternative to add new virtual methods to base class.

Comment: What is your concern about that duplicate pointers? You are already using shared_ptr and not unique_ptr. So if the vector with all objects goes out of scope, the other vector can still be used, which is probably what you want. You can even question if they really have a common base class, but that depends on what the class represents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question.
We sometimes meet such a situation in maintenance of legacy codes which we don’t know who wrote.

> Are there any disadvantages of having two vectors in MyClass … ?

**I think there are no mechanical (or performance) disadvantages.**
If we are struggled to meet the release deadline, we have no choice but to pick such an simple way.
However, storing same vectors twice actually lowers maintainability and **we should consider improving it in the future.**

---

- std::dynamic_pointer_cast (or boost::dynamic_pointer_cast) [[Demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kQQhgAVZRHFUixGK)

If you need `dynamic_pointer_cast` to implement functions like [@Caleth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627324/is-it-good-practice-to-store-copies-of-the-same-shared-pointers-in-different-vec/52628040#52628040) ’s `push_back` / `remove`,
 how about removing `only_derived1` and reluctantly applying just one `dynamic_pointer_cast` in `doSomethingForDerivedObject1()` from the get-go as follows ?
It will make MyClass simpler. Required modification will not be complicated if DerivedObject3 is defined in the future.

```
void MyClass::doSomethingForDerivedObject1()
{
    for (const auto& obj_i : everything)
    {
      if (auto derived1 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedObject1>(obj_i))
        {
           derived1->additionalMethod();
        }
    }
}

void MyClass::doSomethingForDerivedObject3()
{
    for (const auto& obj_i : everything)
    {
      if (auto derived3 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedObject3>(obj_i))
        {
           derived3->additionalMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

---

- Dummy Method as proposed by [@sagi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627324/is-it-good-practice-to-store-copies-of-the-same-shared-pointers-in-different-vec/52627418#52627418) [[Demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3ebZkWR5he5xjuWB)

Declaring virtual function `BaseObject::additionalMethod()` and implementing

```
void DerivedObject2::additionalMethod()
{ 
  /* nothing to do */
}
```

then you can again remove `only_derived1`.
In this method you must implement `DerivedObject3::additionalMethod()` only if DerivedObject3 is defined.

But, although it depends on your constructor or setter code,  if the following case will also occur

```
everything;    ->derived2
only_derived1; ->derived1
```

this method is still insufficient.

---

- Changing Design [[Demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aLjAFjMbRtkZGfKY)

Ideally, we should not use public inheritance to implement objects within "IS-ALMOST-A“ relations, as Herb Sutter says.
The relation between `BaseObject`, `DerivedObject1` and `DerivedObject2` looks like this one.
Since I don’t know whole code of your application I may be wrong, but it will be worthwhile to consider extracting `DerivedObject1::additionalMethod()` as another class or a function pointer and putting its vector in MyClass as a private member.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest this : Store everything in one array , and make a dummy `additionalMethod()` in `DerivedObject2` . Then - just invoke `additionalMethod` for every object .

Alternativly :

> They share a common behavior and methods, but DerivedObject1 has an additional method

Make `DerivedObject1` inherit from `DerivedObject2`

Comment: I thought about making a dummy method, but it doesn't feel like pretty code and it would cluster the class, `additionalMethod()` really doesn't mean anything for `DerivedObject2`. I fear adding it to `DerivedObject2` would confuse people reading the documentation. Also making `DerivedObject1` inherit from `DerivedObject2` wouldn't make much sense (like if the base class if Fruit, and derived classes are Apple and Banana). Plus there may be a `DerivedObject3` in the future. Still, those are solutions but I'm wondering if there are actual disadvantages of having multiple copies of the shared ptr

Comment: @Enaid The disadvantage is wasted space and the complexity of syncing the vectors.  You have to add the same pointer to two vectors and then if you remove an element you need to do it from both vectors.  That extra space and complexity is it's disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your first method is good, the main problem is that you end up duplicating the public members of `vector` to ensure that the consistency of the `Derived` vector.

```
class MyClass
{
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseObject>> BaseObjectVector;
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DerivedObject1>> DerivedObject1Vector;
    BaseObjectVector everything;
    DerivedObject1Vector only_derived1;
public:
    void push_back(shared_ptr<Base> ptr)
    {
        everything.push_back(ptr);
        if (shared_ptr<Derived1> derived = dynamic_ptr_cast<Derived1>(ptr))
        {
            only_derived1.push_back(derived);
        }
    }
    void remove(shared_ptr<Base> ptr)
    {
        base.remove(ptr);
        only_derived1.remove(dynamic_ptr_cast<Derived1>(ptr));
    }
    // dozens more... 
};
```

What you can instead do is provide a view of your `bases` using something like [`boost::range`'s adaptors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html)

```
shared_ptr<Derived1> convert(shared_ptr<Base> ptr)
{
    return dynamic_ptr_cast<Derived1>(ptr);
}

bool not_null(shared_ptr<Derived1> ptr)
{
    return ptr.get();
}

boost::for_each(bases 
              | boost::adaptors::transformed(convert) // Base to Derived
              | boost::adaptors::filtered(not_null)   // Eliminate null
              | boost::adaptors::indirected,          // dereference
                boost::bind(&Derived1::additionalMethod, boost::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: Boost also has it, see [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#dynamic_pointer_cast).